# Demora al realizar primera operación

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy utilizando el cliente MySQL Workbench para administrar una base de datos.

El problema es que cuando lo abro y realizo una primera acción (sea una select, un insert, o simplemente crear un nuevo schema) el cliente se queda bloqueado, como "pensando" durante 3 minutos como mínimo. A veces han llegado a ser 10 minutos.

Cuando termina de pensar, todas las acciones siguientes van fluidas, pero siempre la primera sentencia es la que cuesta. Pero si paro de hacer cosas y pasa un tiempo en el que no hago ninguna consulta, vuelve a pasar, aunque haya dejado el cliente abierto.

Cuando miro el monitor del sistema, el Workbench está haciendo algo que consume casi toda la RAM.

Pero no sé qué puede ser. Hasta hoy no he conseguido localizar la fuente de este problema. Cuando utilizo este programa en clase no ocurre lo mismo, y allí utilizamos ordenadores peores que el mío. ¿Alguien sabe algo al respecto? ¿Qué podría mirar o consultar?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En este url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786870/mysql-slow-on-first-query-then-fast-for-related-queries comentan ese mismo problema

Comment: Muchas gracias. De momento no me ha resuelto el problema, pero me ha iluminado un poco el camino. Parece que describe exactamente el mismo problema que estoy teniendo, y por lo que comentan, tiene que ver con el motor InnoDB, que vuelca todas las tablas en memoria antes de una primera consulta.